# Questions on memorybehavior of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector

I got a bit confused lately about the memory (de)allocation of `std::vectors`

Lets assume I got normal vector of integer:
`std::vector<int> intv;` When I `push_back` some `int`'s it grows by time. And when I leave the scope (i.e.) of the function, it gets deallocated without the need of extra calls.

Great. Lets have another example:

```
struct foo_t{
    std::string bar:
    unsigned int derp;
}
void hurr(){
    std::vector<foo_t> foov;
    foo_t foo;
    foo.bar = "Sup?";
    foo.derp = 1337;
    foov.push_back(foo);
}
```

Okay. When I call `hurr()` the vector gets created, a `foo_t` instance gets created, the instance gets filled and pushed to the vector. So when I leave the function, the vector gets deallocated and the content (here one `foo_t`) gets deallocated, too?

Next example:

```
struct foo_t{
    std::string bar:
    unsigned int derp;
}
std::vector<foo_t> hurr(){
    std::vector<foo_t> foov;
    foo_t foo;
    foo.bar = "Sup?";
    foo.derp = 1337;
    foov.push_back(foo);
    return foov;
}
```

In my understanding, the vector and its contents live in the stack, which gets (eventually) overwritten by time and the vector I have returned and its contents will be useless. Or does it actually returns a copy of the vector with a copy of its contents (requires a Copy-Constructor for the content datatype if its not a POD)?

And something obvious:

```
struct foo_t{
    std::string bar:
    unsigned int derp;
}
std::vector<foo_t*> hurr(){
    std::vector<foo_t*> foov;
    foo_t foo = new foo_t;
    foo->bar = "Sup?";
    foo->derp = 1337;
    foov.push_back(foo);
    return foov;
}
```

Now I have to manually iterate over the vector, delete its contents and then I can safely let the vector fall out of scope, right?

Comment: _"Now I have to manually itterate over the vector, delete its contents and then I can safely let the vector fall out of scope, right?"_ Yes.

Comment: "Now I have to manually itterate over the vector, delete its contents and then I can safely let the vector fall out of scope, right?" That would invalidate the pointers in the returned vector. Unless that's what you want, and it probably isn't, you shouldn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo Depends when _Now_ is supposed to happen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understood that it happens before the function returns: "iterate over the vector, delete its contents *and then* [...] fall out of scope".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ @molbdnilo "Now" is after I used the vector returned by `hurr()` and its not needed anymore.

Comment: The vector's contents are dynamic storage, not "stack"  (no answers mentioned this yet?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example:

```
struct foo_t{
    std::string bar;
    unsigned int derp;
};
void hurr(){
    std::vector<foo_t> foov;
    foo_t foo;
    foo.bar = "Sup?";
    foo.derp = 1337;
    foov.push_back(foo);
}
```

After `hurv()` finished, `foov` and `foo` are both freed.

```
std::vector<foo_t> hurr(){
    std::vector<foo_t> foov;
    foo_t foo;
    foo.bar = "Sup?";
    foo.derp = 1337;
    foov.push_back(foo);
    return foov;
}
```

the result `std::vector<foo_t>` of `hurr()` is valid with 1 `foo_t` in it and it's valid.
The `return foov;` *may* call a copy contructor of `std::vector<foo_t>`, and it have its free to not make that copy, see [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Anyway, from C++11, you can write this:

```
struct foo_t{
    std::string bar;
    unsigned int derp;
    // we will copy the string anyway, pass-by-value
    foo_t(std::string bar_, unsigned int d_)
        : bar(std::move(bar_)), derp(d_) {}
};
std::vector<foo_t> hurr(){
    std::vector<foo_t> foov;
    // This is better, in place construction, no temporary
    foov.emplace_back("Sup?", 1337);
    // This require a temporary
    foov.push_back(foo_t{"Sup?", 1337});
    return foov;
}
```

And, for the last example, yes, you *have to manually itterate over the vector, delete its contents and then I can safely let the vector fall out of scope* when you no longer want to use the result of `hurr()`, (not in `hurr()`)

Comment: you missed the point of `emplace_back`. It's whole point is to construct in-place, avoiding the need of a temporary. You should do `emplace_back("sup", 1337)`

Comment: @bolov actually, it can't be compiled with `emplace_back("sup", 1337)`, `emplace_back` need a constructor, right?

Comment: yes it does, but `emplace_back` will do the same as `push_back` in this case, i.e. a move a temporary into the vector.

Comment: @Danh yes, it can and that's how it should be used: `emplace_back("sup", 1337)`. Yes, it needs a constructor. It uses the appropriate constructor of the `value_type` to construct the object **in place**. Think of it as getting some arguments and then passing those arguments to the constructor of `value_type`. If you pass it `foo_t{"Sup?", 1337}` then you already create a temporary and then `emplace_back` basically calls the copy or move ctor of `value_type`, which is the same as push_back.

Comment: I like the usage of c++11 here with a constructor and a copy constructor for the struct. Anyway, is there a difference between a struct and a all public class anymore if I add the constructors to the struct? Which would be preferable?

Comment: @BenediktMokroß AFACT, there is no difference, see [C++ concepts: PODType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType), except that, you don't have a parameterless contructor, (from C++11 you can add it again by ctor() = default, though)

Comment: @Danh In your last example `bar_` is copied twice. Did you mean `foo_t(std::string bar_, unsigned int d_) : bar(std::move(bar_)), derp(d_) {}`?

Comment: @Danh I think that second copy (in initialization list) can't be elided, [for example, see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33873333/4899740).

Answer (score 3):

```
foov.push_back(foo);
```

Actually, you constructed a `foo_v` and you pushed it back, which actually created a new `foo_v` and called the copy constructor with `foov` as a paremeter. Use [`emplace_back`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323722/getting-around-copy-semantics-in-c/40323764#40323764) if you want to avoid this.

```
return foov;
```

The compiler may optimize this using return value optimization. See [this short program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3442c38380fbe573) I've made running on coliru as an example. Refer to the other excellent answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

```
std::vector<foo_t*> foov;
/* add elements to foov with new */
```

> Now I have to manually itterate over the vector, delete its contents and then I can safely let the vector fall out of scope, right?

Yes, you do. For the same reasons

```
int* a = new int();
```

Will not `delete a;` when `a` dies.

Answer (score 2):

> So when I leave the function, the vector gets deallocated and the
>   content (here one `foo_t`) gets deallocated, too?

Yes. And if `foo_t` had nontrivial destructor, it would be called.

> Or does it actually returns a copy of the vector with a copy of its
>   contents (requires a Copy-Constructor for the content datatype if its
>   not a POD)?

Yes, in this case it returns a copy. Modern compilers are likely to call copy constructor for `std::vector`, which, in turn, will call copy constructor of the contained type for each element. C++17 introduces guaranteed return value optimization (RVO), so the copy constructor of your vector will not be called. Nevertheless, if you set high optimization level, modern compiler may use RVO too.

> Now I have to manually iterate over the vector, delete its contents
>   and then I can safely let the vector fall out of scope, right?

Yes, you are right. Consider using smart pointers, if you do not want to iterate manually.

Comment: In my [test program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3442c38380fbe573), g++ in `-O0` *actually* seems to make use of RVO. *edit: * i actually didn't compile in `-O0` in that program, but if you specify it you get the same results.

Comment: Usage of smartpointers was another Example for my question which I left out.

Comment: Even if there's no copy elision, the move-constructor will be used (if the contained type is nothrow-moveable)